# Can the community package of Gitlab run enterprise edition?

Tags: arch-linux, gitlab

I'm wondering if `community/gitlab` can be installed and used for Enterprise Edition (EE) or if it is only capable of running Community Edition (CE).

https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/gitlab/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented with installing the package, and it turns out that it cannot run EE, since it is a different code base.